# Does QField support repeating a certain question based on user input?

Tags: qfield

I am developing a form to survey households with their information in every house. In ODK there is a repeat function. Is there a similar function in QField. So that the user inputs the information about the apartment and indicates the number of Households, then the program repeats for each household the questions related to them. Is that possible?

Comment: It seem that using a 1-n relation with a linked table could be a solution, have a look at that